# Can annotations be nested in a class in Java?

Tags: java, class, interface, annotations

I'm trying to understand how this annotation is invoked @WebMethod

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService          //<----- is this annotation nested in WebService class
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface TimeServer {


    @WebMethod String getTimeAsString();  //<-------is this nested in a class too
    @WebMethod long getTimeAsElapsed();
}
```

According to my import javax.jws.WebMethod, and to Java docs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/jws/WebMethod.html
`public @interface WebMethod` is described.

Is the @WebMethod annotation defined as the WebMethod class?
Could the source code for the WebMethod class be something like this?

```
Public class WebMethod{
   //members
   //methods
  public @interface WebMethod{ //annotation definition in class, is this possible
  }
}
```

If this is not the case, please let me how it's done with a simple example.

Comment: What would the outer class be for?

Comment: it's the import javax.jws.WebMethod with nested the annotation

Comment: I repeat. What would the outer class accomplish? You haven't answered that.

Answer (score 2):

No, like it says in the Javadoc you linked to, this is defined as

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value=METHOD)
public @interface WebMethod
```

So this is an annotation (@interface) that you put on a method (@Target(value=METHOD)).

@WebMethod is not "nested" into @WebService, those are two independent annotations (but of course, they work in concert). That one goes on a method and the other on a class is defined by the @Target.

Answer (score 0):

While that does not seems to be the case in this specific instance I ran across the same question of whether inner annotations where ok.

According to my experiments this works

Annotation definition:

```
// pkg2/I.java
package pkg2;

import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

public final class I {
    private I(){
    }
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface Inner {}
}
```

Usage:

```
// pkg/C.java
package pkg;

import pkg2.I;

@I.Inner
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         System.out.println(C.class.getAnnotation(I.Inner.class));
    }
}
```

Running:

```
$ java pkg/C
@pkg2.I$Inner()
```